# How to add custom error pages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages, 404

I'm having a problem since I'm new to Magento.

how can I create a custom error pages in my Magento 2 site?

For example these pages: 500, 401, 403, and 404. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can customize (404) page from admin

```
Content->Pages->404 Not Found->Edit->content
```

here you can change whatever content you need.

If you look programmatically solution, add the below content in your `<root-magent>/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList">
<arguments>
    <argument name="handlerClassesList" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="class"
            xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\NoRouteHandler</ite
            m>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">200</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
</type>
```

add this content in above mentioned controller

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller;
class NoRouteHandler implements \Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerInterface {

    public function process(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
        $moduleName= 'cms';
        $controllerName = 'index';
        $actionName= 'index';

        $request
        ->setModuleName($moduleName)
        ->setControllerName($controllerName)
        ->setActionName($actionName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this controller you can set whatever module/controller/actionname for 404 page.

follow this [link](https://onlyecommerce.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/customizing-magento-error-pages-404-503-500/) to set 401,403,500 page

Comment: Hi bro thanks for this wonderful answer!!! Thank you for helping me :)